# Get data-id of each element with specific classname as string, not as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html list like this:

```
<div id="list">
   <div class="special" data-id="TZ2"></div>
   <div class="special" data-id="KJ1"></div>
   <div class="" data-id="LLT"></div>
   <div class="" data-id="UV3"></div>
   <div class="special" data-id="JQT"></div>
</div>
```

I want to **get all `data-id`s of divs with classname `special`, splitted by a comma, as a string.**

```
var myIDs = $("#list > div").each(function() {
   $(".special", this).data('id');
});
```

With this way I get the myIDs variable as an object, but I just want the `data-id`s as a string list, like this:

```
TZ2,KJ1,JQT
```

I also tried this one, after running the each function:

```
var myIDsString = myIDs.data('id');
```

But then I only get the `data-id` of the first object. What's my fail?

---

```js
var myIDs = $("#list > div").each(function() {
   $(".special", this).data('id');
});

var myIDsString = myIDs.data('id');

console.log(myIDsString)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
   <div class="special" data-id="TZ2"></div>
   <div class="special" data-id="KJ1"></div>
   <div class="" data-id="LLT"></div>
   <div class="" data-id="UV3"></div>
   <div class="special" data-id="JQT"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BenFortune Ah, that could work, thx for the tip, I will try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all Id into array then convert it into string using toString() function.

```js
let myIDs = [];

$(document).find('.special').each(function() {
  let id = $(this).data('id');
  myIDs.push(id);
})

console.log(myIDs.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
  <div class="special" data-id="TZ2"></div>
  <div class="special" data-id="KJ1"></div>
  <div class="" data-id="LLT"></div>
  <div class="" data-id="UV3"></div>
  <div class="special" data-id="JQT"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Big thx for your example / help! I modified it a bit for me, but yes, it's exactly what I was looking for. A bit noob like fail by myself.

Comment: Why not just use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: Possibly 1 liner: `$(document).find('.special').map((e) => $(e).data("id")).get(0).join(", ")`